# Using Perl hash table to delete vowels in string, but output is always empty

Tags: perl, split, hashtable, exists

I'm trying to write a short script in Perl to go through a an array of strings provided by the user, check in a hash table to see if there are vowels in the strings, then return the strings minus the vowels. I know this would be easier to accomplish using regex, but the parameters for the problem state that a hash table, `exists()`, and `split()` must be used. This is the script I have so far:

```
my @vowels = qw(a e i o u A E I O U);
my %vowel;
foreach $v (@vowels) {
   $vowel{$v} = undef;
}
foreach $word (@ARGV) {
   my @letter_array = split(undef,$word);
}
foreach $letter (@letter_array) {
   print($letter) if !exists($vowel{$letter})
}
print "\n"
```

Input: hello

Expected output: hll

Actual output: *nothing*

There are no error messages, so I know it's not a syntax error.
Any ideas what I'm messing up? I'm much more comfortable with Python and this is one of my first attempts at Perl.

Comment: In Perl it is generally strongly recommended to _always_ start programs with `use warnings;` and `use strict;`.  The first is just absolutely critical, the second forces you to always declare a variable, what leads to all manner of good things and prevents many errors.

Comment: 1) ALWAYS use `use strict; use warnings;`! 2) Learn to indent properly. /// Either one of these would have found your error!

Comment: Correct perl to split a string into individual characters is `split(//,$word)`

Answer (score 2):

You should `use strict` not to mess visibility of your variables.
If you require perl version `5.12` or higher it would be used automatically.

So your list `@letter_array` exists only in `foreach my $word (@ARGV)` loop. That's why it's empty in the end.

If you want to fix that you'll get the following code:

```perl
#!/usr/bin/env perl

use strict;
use warnings;

my @vowels = qw( a e i o u y A E I O U Y );
my %vowel;

foreach my $v (@vowels) {
   $vowel{$v} = undef;
}

my @letter_array;
foreach my $word (@ARGV) {
    @letter_array = split //, $word;
}

foreach my $letter (@letter_array) {
    print($letter) if !exists($vowel{$letter})
}

print "\n"
```

But this code is still not practical.

1. If you would get more that 1 word in the input, you'll show only the last one, because the @ letter_array overwrites each time.
2. You can use `map` to get the hash of vowels much easier without using extra variables.
3. You can use less loops if you would handle each word right after reading it.
4. You can also use `unless` if you want to check `if not` to make it prettier and more perl-style.
5. Don't use split on undef. Better use `split //, $word`
6. You can use `for` instead of `foreach` because it's the same but shorter :)

So you can get an optimised solution.

```perl
#!/usr/bin/env perl

use 5.012;
use warnings;


my %vowels = map { $_ => undef } qw( a e i o u y A E I O U Y );

for my $word (@ARGV) {
    my @letters = split //, $word;
    for my $letter (@letters) {
        print $letter unless exists $vowels{$letter};
    }
    print ' ';
}
print "\n"
```

Result:

```
$ perl delete_vowels.pl hello world
hll wrld
```

Comment: 1.  There **must** be `use warnings;` !!  Always.  Then, for instance, that terrible `split` on `undef` _would_ complain; want `@letters = split //, $word;`  (splitting on empty pattern, `//`, returns all characters) 2. "_code is still not practical._"  -- i'd say it's _wrong_, not only impractical, for the reason you then name: it works only for the last word.

Comment: `use v5.11` or above automatically enables strict, but `use v5.10` does not.

Comment: @tobyink, One of the features (unicode_strings) was incomplete in 5.12, so I always go with 5.14 over 5.12. 5.11? That's just weird.

Comment: @zdim
Agreed. I was trying to use the same syntax for split, not to confuse the questioner

Comment: @Narek "_Agreed. I was trying to use the same syntax for split, not to confuse the questioner_" -- oh i see; I'd strongly suggest to correct it -- and mention it; and add warnings.  Passing `undef` to `split` is just wrong, and with warnings on it yells as it should (and I'd state that too); it works merely because of Perl always trying to make things work.  (And I was surprised that it works -- the [docs say](https://perldoc.perl.org/functions/split#split-/PATTERN/) for it `/PATTERN/` and `undef` ain't it I think...)

Comment: @ikegami, I'm not especially recommending anybody uses Perl 5.11. Just stating that `use v5.11` was the first `use VERSION` that automatically enables strict. This answer claims that `use v5.10` enables strict, but that is false.

Comment: "_Fixed_" -- cool, thanks :).   Btw, a comment for "_Don't use split on undef. Better use `split //, $word`_", just in case: using `undef` in `split` is plain _wrong_.  With warnings on for that we get: "_Use of uninitialized value in regexp compilation_"  (because the first argument -- the pattern to split on -- is a regex pattern)

Answer (score 2):

An alternative and more compact method of achieving the same thing is to use the substitute operator, "[s](https://perldoc.perl.org/functions/s)" with a regular expression that matches the vowels.

Here is an example

```
use strict;
use warnings;

for my $word (@ARGV)
{
    print $word =~ s/[aeiou]//gri;
}
```

or more succinctly like this

```
use strict;
use warnings;

for (@ARGV)
{
    print s/[aeiou]//gri;
}
```

Key points to note

1. the regular expression uses the [Character Class](https://perldoc.perl.org/perlrecharclass) `[aeiou]` to match a single lower-case vowel.
2. the substitute operator has been given three options

   - the `i` option to force a case insensitive match. This means the [Character Class](https://perldoc.perl.org/perlrecharclass) `[aeiou]` will match both uppercase and lower-case vowels.
   - the `g` option to make the substitute match all instances of the regular expression -- in this instance it will match against all the vowels in the string.
   - the `r` option (which is a newish addition to Perl) to get the substitute  operator to return the substituted string.

running that gives this

```
$ perl try.pl hello world
hllwrld
```

Comment: `hllwrld$`, really, since you didn't print a line feed. Fixed: `use v5.14; use warnings; say join " ", map { s/[aeiou]//gri } @ARGV;`